# Airflow triggers Sagemaker job in test mode

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I've an Airflow(`v1.10.12`) dag that triggers a Sagemaker Processor job as part of one of it's tasks.  I've written few tests(pytest `6.2.2`) to check the basic sanity of the dag.
It seems like just fetching the dag by id from DagBag triggers a Sagemaker job. i.e When I do `pytest test_file_name.py`, a job is triggered which isn't ideal.

```
from airflow.models import DagBag

class TestSagemakerDAG:
    @classmethod
    def setup(cls):

        cls.dagbag = DagBag()
        cls.dag = DagBag().get_dag(dag_id='sagemaker-processor')

    def test_dag_loaded(self):
        """
        To verify if dags are loaded onto the dagabag
        :return:
        """
        assert self.dagbag.import_errors == {}
        assert self.dag is not None
        assert len(self.dag.tasks) == 2
```

For more clarity this is how the Sagemaker Processor job(`sagemaker 2.24.1`) definition looks like

```
def initiate_sage_maker_job(self, session):
    return Processor(
        image_uri=self.ecr_uri,
        role=self.iam_role,
        instance_count=self.instance_count,
        instance_type=self.instance_type,
        base_job_name=self.processor_name,
        sagemaker_session=session,
    ).run()
```

And the boto3(`v 1.16.63`) session is generated as

```
def get_session(self):
    boto_session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = boto_session.client('sagemaker', region_name=self.region)
    session = sagemaker.session.Session(boto_session=boto_session, sagemaker_client=client)
    return session
```

Finally, the Dag itself

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

with DAG('sagemaker-processor',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='@hourly',
         ) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_current_date',
        bash_command='date'
    )
    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='sagemaker_trigger', python_callable=initiate_sage_maker_job()   
    )
    
    t1 >> t2
```

I'm just trying to import dags from a folder and check import errors, check upstream and downstream list.
On a side note, I've made sure the Dag is turned off on the Airflow UI and or to execute `airflow scheduler` to start queueing tasks. It's really just a standard test I want to execute using Pytest.

The issue pops up as follows

```
Job Name:  airflow-ecr-test-2021-02-26-21-10-39-935
Inputs:  []
Outputs:  []
[2021-02-26 16:10:39,935] {session.py:854} INFO - Creating processing-job with name airflow-ecr-test-2021-02-26-21-10-39-935
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/Ajeya.Kempegowda/dags/sample_mwaa.py", line 31, in <module>
    initiate_sage_maker_job()
  File "/Users/Ajeya.Kempegowda/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/processing.py", line 180, in run
    experiment_config=experiment_config,
  File "/Users/Ajeya.Kempegowda/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/processing.py", line 695, in start_new
    processor.sagemaker_session.process(**process_args)
  File "/Users/Ajeya.Kempegowda/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 856, in process
    self.sagemaker_client.create_processing_job(**process_request)
  File "/Users/Ajeya.Kempegowda/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ajeya.Kempegowda/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the CreateProcessingJob operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

The error displayed says `TokenExpired` but it really stems while creating a job itself.

Is there something obvious I'm missing while testing airflow? My understanding is that `airflow scheduler` should queue up dags and only when told to execute(`Turn on dag on Airflow UI/CLI`) the tasks must be triggered.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @gold_cy it's in the first chunk of code in the post - 
`cls.dagbag = DagBag(); cls.dag = DagBag().get_dag(dag_id='sagemaker-processor')`
[Dagbag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagbag/index.html) - That's how Apache Airflow loads multiple dag files

Comment: then in that case you should be patching DagBag, that’s the reason it’s trying to run real code

Comment: @gold_cy Aaah! You're right. I patched Sagemaker call instead as don't want to mock Dagbag(Tests on Airflow is of interest). Thank you for your time and help!